# Are there any cognitive tests, or test suites, available on the Android?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, measurement, test

Are there any cognitive tests, or test suites, available on the Android? I'm thinking something like quantified-mind.com but for android. The closest I've been able to find is Brainturk Brain Training, but there doesn't appear to be a way to export results.

It's similar to this question, but for the android: [Are there any cognitive test (or test suites) available on the iPad?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/506/are-there-any-cognitive-test-or-test-suites-available-on-the-ipad#)

My 4 main criteria are (like [here](http://measuredme.com/2012/11/one-of-the-self-tracking-projects-that-i-always-wanted-to-do-was-to-determine-the-impact-of-sleep-diet-and-exercise-regimen.html/)):

- app should simply measure cognitive or mental skills/abilities, as
  opposed to training or improving them measurement methods used in the
- app should be as close to scientific as possible (a lot of game apps
  failed this requirement)
- the tests should take as little time as possible (preferably under 5 min)
- have a way to export data (e.g. into csv)

Answer (score 3):

The N-back task is a typical test for cognitive capabilities. There are many version of it in the Google play store. You could try a few of them and see which suits your needs best.

Comment: ah yes, the N-back. I have indeed tried a number of N-backs on the Android but i don't believe any of them allowed me to export the data from the device. Do you know of any that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Sadly I do not. I only looked at one or two, but I haven't used them seriously.